# Catch Key events from a library

Tags: c#, keyboard-events

I develop a library that is referenced by a SmartDevice project and a WinForm project.

So it's used on distinct material devices. I've the list of these devices but difference is on the keyboard... Some have a "full" keyboard, some other a "partial" keyboard...

I want to do manage the keyboard layout homogeneously and will do it in my library (not a winform project).

I've an abstract "material" class in which I define all events raised and each distinct material herits from this class.

My question is : how can I catch application keys events in each of theses subclasses to map it as I wish?

Hope I'm clear enough...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx